# How to handle weird behaviours with jQuery application using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a stabilization of an old application which is developed using jQuery. In order to stabilize it, I added a method which, using javascript, checks for document is ready `document.readyState === "complete"`and ajax calls have been completed `jQuery.active == 0` before interacting with elements.

But I still see following kind of issues -

1. Even though element is present on a page, Selenium WebDriver unable to find it even with polling mechanism which has some timeout set. However we can find same element, by checking in DOM.
2. UI is distorted and when WebDriver tries to click on an element, it gives error `Element click intercepted`. However same element can be clicked manually.
3. Even application has jQuery, when we execute javascrit `jQuery.active == 0` through WebDriver, it results into `jQuery is not defined`. However if we execute same query through browser console, it returns correct result.

For all above, when I said something worked that means I've checked that in same browser instance which WebDriver had launched.

Could you please help how this can be resolved? I have been struggling for a week to stabilize this.

Comment: This question is a little vague. However the best way to stabilize is to have selenium wait for the elements in the correct fashion (depending on waht you want to do). Is there a more specific issue we can help you address?

Comment: Could you post some of the HTML for the page you are automating, along with your Selenium code you are running? You can add explicit waits on elements, run javascript clicks to work around `Element click intercepted`, switch into `iframe` to find elements, etc. Checking `document.readyState` is not always the best Selenium practice to see if the page is fully loaded. There are workarounds to the issues you are encountering but we can't help much without any code or HTML to reference.

Comment: Try moving jquery into head and remove async/defer attributes. Make sure element is not in iframe and use === for comparison rather than ==

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario but I could not get how to implement your statement - `Try moving jquery into head and remove async/defer attributes.` Could you please help more on this?

Comment: In other words if the jquery script tag is in the body somewhere or has a async/defer attribute, just move it into the head and remove those attributes.

Comment: @pguardiario, I could not see jQuery script tag in DOM but could see `async` attribute like - `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="event-bus" src="./Lib/UILayer/myevent-bus.js?v=78351"></script>` but that is under head tag

Comment: No jquery script tag? I guess I don't understand what you're doing in that case, sorry.